# Closing a dialog box if ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using dialog box for add new users to db , I want to close dialog box if validation pass and user successfully saved. please advice

```
   $('.add_user_link a').each(function () {

            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                });

            $link.click(function () {

              $dialog.dialog('open');

                $('#add_user').submit(function () {

                    url = '/user/useradd/';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        url: $('#add_user').attr('action'),
                        data: $('#add_user').serializeArray(),

                        success: function (data) {

                            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                            var result = json_obj['result'];
                            var lname = json_obj['lname'];
                            var email = json_obj['email'];
                            var fname = json_obj['fname'];

                            if (!result) {

                                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                            }
                            else {
//                              
                                document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = email;

                                var fname_count = $("label[id*='errorfname']").length;

                                    $('input[name=fname]').after('<label id="errorfname"></label>');
                                    document.getElementById('errorfname').innerHTML = fname;



                                var lname_count = $("label[id*='errorlname']").length;
                                if (lname_count == 0) {
                                    $('input[name=lname]').after('<label id="errorlname"></label>');
                                    document.getElementById('errorlname').innerHTML = lname;
                                }




                            }



                        }


                    });
                    return false;
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

I'm getting this error

> jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

With

```
$dialog.dialog('close')
```

You've already set a variable for your dialog in the click function which should be in scope so you don't need to reselect it.

UPDATE:
Element IDs should be unique so you should make the dialog ID unique when adding it for a link if there are multiple links. Otherwise, you will select multiple dialog elements when you do this $('#dialog') when there are mulitiple links.

When you do this:

```
$dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
```

the ID value "dialog" should be something unique, like "dialog1", "dialog2", etc.

Comment: it works. but when I repopen dialog box it comes with old data. how can I open without prevoious filled data

Comment: this is the anchor tag for the link div class="add_user_link"><a href="/user/useradd" id="add-user-ico" title="Add User"><i class="fa fa-user"> </i>Add New
        User</a></div>

Comment: you need to reset the dialog contents if that's what should happen.